# What is the name of this patience style 2 deck card game

Tags: identify-this-game

I was playing a card game online but I don't know the name.

- The game is played with two decks.
- Approx 1 dealt face up in 10 columns with the rest kept for dealing but only 5 at a time despite 10 columns.
- Cards can only be moved to the next card in suit (you build packs from K to Ace), but you can move an entire column of non suited cards on top.
- Only Kings can go in column spaces.
- Full suit doesn't leave the game until it is full and free if additional cards on top of it.

Comment: Here is a list of solitaire variants: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_patience_games

Comment: Not sure what "Approx 1 dealt face up in 10 columns" means...did you mean "1 dealt face up in approx 10 columns"? (assuming approx mean approximately)

Comment: 10 columns face up but i can't remember how many cards in each.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the game you are thinking of could be [Spider Solitaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_(solitaire)) or a variant of it.

The game:

- is a solo style Patience/Solitaire game
- is played with two decks
- consists of 10 columns
- cards are stacked with like suited cards from K to Ace in order to remove them
- Only Kings may be placed on empty spaces

You can find the how-to-play rules here:
[Bicycle Cards: How to play Spider Solitaire](http://www.bicyclecards.com/how-to-play/spider-solitaire/)

A common game may look like this at the start (Source [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_(solitaire))):
[image: Spider Solitaire]

<sup>Sidenote: If you want to give spider Solitaire a go, try searching for it from your start menu. Some versions of Windows have the game installed by default.</sup>

Comment: No sorry marco the cards are dealt face up.

Comment: @Solitaire The cards are dealt face up, with the majority of the cards being kept in the stack. When you pull from the stack you add a new card to each column. Perhaps you played a variant where _all_ the cards were in the stack instead of most?